# Change width of Eclipse filename tabs

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

In Eclipse, is it possible to adjust the width of the filename tabs across the top of the open file? At the moment each tab shows only the first 12 characters of a filename. As java class names are usually quite long, this isn't enough to distinguish the files eg:

```
ExistingCustomer.java
ExistingCustomerService.java
ExistingCustomerController.java
```

Becomes:

```
ExistingCust...
ExistingCust...
ExistingCust...
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I think this is not possible out of the box. Maybe there are plugins that can achieve this but I'm not aware of any standard eclipse setting serving this purpose.

I know that eclipse tries to display as much as possible of each file's name but if you open too many files at the same time, the part control has to trim the size of the part taps in order to display some more.

If you find the corresponding setting or a plugin for the intended behavior, please let me know ;)

Comment: Thanks Shi. I think I'll use this as another justification for ditching eclipse and switching to intelliJ and Sublime Text. Life seems to be good without eclipse ;)